# two arrays with the same value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.

I need to make a foreach where it loops the values that is the same in both arrays. The arrays are not in same order and one of the arrays have more values than the other array.

I could do this.

```
foreach($array1 as $items1)
{
  foreach($array2 as $items2)
  {
     if($items1 == $items2)
     Echo "Match!";
  }
}
```

But that takes a lot of time to load

**Edit**

I dont get any matches.

**Array 1**

```
$array1 = array();

    while($fetch = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
          $array1[] = array("a" => $fetch['value']);
    }
```

**Array 2**

```
$filename = "test.txt";

$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

if ($fp) {
$array2 = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}
```

**CODE**

```
array_unshift($array2,"b");

$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Why do you need to loop? Why not simply use an [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)?

Comment: follow the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
$matches = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP in built function [array_intersect()](http://php.net/array_intersect)

```
<?php
  $array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
  $array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
  $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
  print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

> Note : Returns an array containing all of the values in array1 whose values exist in all of the parameters.

Comment: My arrays is only Single Dimensional Arrays. Is it possible to ad "a" and "b" first in the array?

Comment: It's only like: array("green", "red", "blue"); no "a" =>

Comment: Yes it possible using `array_unshift($yourArray,"a");`

Comment: No. My array is empty